# How to publish single parquet file after processing in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a parquet file having 100,000 records.
I want to process all records with parallelism and my processing will generate some more columns.
So if My parquet file has 3 columns and 100,000 records, my file looks like as below-

```
col A    col B     colC
aa         bb       cc
aa1        bb1      cc1
```

After getting processed in parallely , I want a new parquet file with same columns and 3more columns. My output looks like this -

```
col A    col B     colC     colD      colE       colF
aa         bb       cc       dd        ee          ff
aa1        bb1      cc1      dd1       ee1         ff1
```

I want to know -

- After running parallely in spark nodes, how can i combine all the results into 1 parquet file?
- How can i add more columns to an existing file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can always repartition your data to a single partition with

```
df.repartition(1)
```

It will do the work if you are just experimenting, or working with small datasets (100,000 record with reasonable length can be considered small data). But if you want your application to scale gracefully, you should avoid such aggressive repartitioning and write several parquet files, What is so bad with having several output files?

Regarding your second question, parquet files designed to be immutable, so the most straight forward way to do what you want will be to read the data, add the relevant columns and save the data back as parquet (override exiting files, or save the modified data to a new directory).

Comment: If my input is one parquet file, I want corresponding one parquet file as output with new added columns. Won't writing so many parquet files will increase the disk space? also, how can i parallely process my input parquet file?

Comment: More files will not increase disk space significantly, having 10 files of X is pretty much the same as having one file of 10X. The only difference with many files is that you will have to store a bit more meta data chunks, but more often than not it is negligible in compare to the size of the actual data.

Spark handles parallelism for you, just look for a few examples of how to work with Spark. Spark will split the input file to partition and process each of them on a separate executor, The larger you input file the more input splits you have.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I recommend you to not create one single file from Apache Spark, this will break the performance of the tool. If you are doing storage in a HDFS I suggest you to run this command after you finish your mapReduce:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output/dir/on/hdfs/ /desired/local/output/file.txt
```

Or, you can take a function that can merge these files for you like this:

```
textFiles = [f for f in listdir(outputPath) if isfile(join(outputPath, f))]

files = [f for f in textFiles if f.startswith('part-')]
files.sort()

filePath = outputPath + '/consolidate_file'
outputFile = open(filePath, 'w')

for i in files:
    tmpFile = open(outputPath + '/' + i, 'r')
    outputFile.write(tmpFile.read())

outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Thiago. 
I can try this approach. But creating multiple parquet file won't be unnecessarily using disk space or HDFS. 
Also, how can i parallely process my input parquet file?

Comment: This is not going to take a lot of unnecessarily space. But to process parallely if you use sqlContext.read.parquet("file") this process already be parallelized according your Spark default configuration.